# Trace of a nonlinear matrix equation (cont'd)

Tags: matrices, ds.dynamical-systems, matrix-analysis, recurrences, matrix-equations

Let $X_0$ be a trace-one positive definite matrix, i.e. $X_0>0$, $\mathrm{tr}(X_0)=1$. Let $A>0$ and consider the following iteration
$$
X_{k+1} = X_k^{1/2}AX_k^{1/2},\quad k\geq 0,\quad (\star)
$$
where $X_k^{1/2}$ denotes the (principal) square root of $X_k$.

> **My question:** Is it true that if *there exists* $X_0$ as above such that $(\star)$ is trace-preserving starting from $X_0$, i.e. $\mathrm{tr}(X_{k+1})=\mathrm{tr}(X_{k})=1$ for all $k\geq 0$, then $A=I$?

If $X_0$ and $A$ are scalars this is clearly true. Moreover, it is easy to see that $A$ cannot be such that $A> I$ or $A< I$, but I cannot quite prove that $A$ must be the identity.

Thanks for your help.

---

**Addendum 1.** Note that by applying to $(\star)$ an orthogonal change of basis $T$ which diagonalizes $A$, we can rewrite $(\star)$ as
$$
\tilde{X}_{k+1}= \tilde{X}_k^{1/2} D \tilde{X}_k^{1/2} \quad (\star\star)
$$
where $\tilde{X}_k:=T^\top X_k T$ and $D:=T^\top AT>0$ is diagonal.

---

**Addendum 2.** A "simpler" version of this question was answered in the affirmative [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249684/trace-of-a-nonlinear-matrix-equation/249738).

---

**Addendum 3.** My attempts so far were based on working with the "simplified" dynamics $(\star\star)$. Namely, consider the partition $D=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}D_1 & 0 \\ 0 & D_2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ with $D_1>I_{n_1}$ and $D_2<I_{n_2}$ (in the other cases, e.g. $D_1> I_{n_1}$, $D_2=I_{n_2}$, it is easy to show that $\mathrm{tr}(\tilde{X}_1)\neq 1$). Now by partitioning $\tilde X_0^{1/2}$ and $\tilde X_1$ accordingly to the block decomposition of $D$, we get
$$
\tilde{X}_1=\begin{bmatrix}(\tilde X_1)_{11} & (\tilde X_1)_{12} \\ (\tilde X_1)_{12}^\top & (\tilde X_1)_{22}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{11}D_1(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{11} + (\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12}D_2(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12}^\top & (\ast) \\ (\ast)^\top & (\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12}^\top D_1(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12} + (\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{22}D_2(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{22} \end{bmatrix},
$$
with the constraint $\mathrm{tr}(\tilde X_0)=1$ which now reads as 
$$
\mathrm{tr}\left((\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{11}(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{11} + (\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12}(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12}^\top\right)+\mathrm{tr}\left((\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12}^\top (\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{12} + (\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{22}(\tilde X_0^{1/2})_{22}\right)=1.
$$
Now my conjecture is that $\mathrm{tr}(\tilde X_2)\neq 1$ for all $\tilde{X_0}>0$, $\mathrm{tr}(\tilde{X_0})=1$, (indeed, it is easy to find examples for which $\mathrm{tr}(\tilde X_1)= 1$). My idea is to use the same block decomposition for $\tilde X_2$ and then exploit some "trace inequalities" applied to the diagonal blocks. However I didn't manage to conclude anything so far.

---

**Addendum 4.** A more general version of this question which I suspect hold true (actually, for the $2\times 2$ case, it does hold true) is the following one:

> Is it true that if there exists $X_0\ge 0$, $\mathrm{tr}(X_0)=1$, such that $(\star)$ is trace-preserving starting from $X_0$, i.e. $\mathrm{tr}(X_{k+1})=\mathrm{tr}(X_{k})=1$ for all $k\geq 0$, then $X_{k+1}=X_k^{1/2}AX_k^{1/2}=X_k$ for all $k\geq 0$?

Comment: May there be a cycle of length 2, that is, $X_2=X_0$? I do not see why not.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Since $A>0$ it looks improbable to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Of course $A>0$ automatically: we need $X_0^{-1/2}X_1X_0^{-1/2}=A=X_1^{-1/2}X_0X_1^{-1/2}.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Yes, still it's not straightforward to me to find a pair of unit trace $X_0$, $X_1$ satisfying the above constraint for $A\neq I$. (In case of diagonal $X_0$, $X_1$ it's not possible, I would say).

Comment: @FedorPetrov I can show that cycles of any length are impossible if $A\ne I$. Alas, this doesn't help much with the original problem unless $X_j$ are uniformly non-degenerate (which is never true in the interesting case $\det A<1$), so we are still nowhere...

Comment: Why does the given iteration rule involve the square root factorization of the current state as opposed to the Cholesky factorization?  More precisely, why not replace ($\star$) with $$X_{k+1} = L_k B (L_k B)^T \quad \text{where $X_k = L_k L_k^T$ and $A=B B^T$}$$ which admits a global solution given by $X_{k} = (L_0 B^{k}) (L_0 B^{k})^T$ that may be used to conclude (e.g., by contradiction) that $A=I_n$.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: Yes, of course replacing the principal square root with the Cholesky square root makes the problem trivial. However the principal square root has remarkable properties that the Cholesky factor does not have (the most obvious one is that the principal square root is positive (semi)definite). In the problem I'm investigating, I need such properties.

Comment: @fedja: Could you please explain how you proved that cycles of any length are impossible if $A\neq I$? (Even though it's not a solution, it might give more insights on the problem...)

Comment: Certainly. Assume $A=diag(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. For a self-adjoint matrix $Z$, let $v(Z)$ be the vector whose coordinates are the diagonal entries of $Z$.  Assume $Y^2=XAX$. Then $v(Y^2)=(X\circ X^T)v(A)$ while $v(X^2)=(X\circ X^T)v(I)$ where $Z\circ T$ is the Schur (element-wise) product of $Z$ and $T$. Since $X\circ X^T$ is positive-definite, we get $\langle v(Y^2)-v(X^2),v(A)-v(I)\rangle>0$ if $v(A)\ne v(I)$, so we drift in one direction every time with no chance to return.

Comment: If that is the case, and noting that the only fixed point occurs when $A=I_n$, then we get a contradiction because the sequence is clearly bounded (alternatively, the set of unit trace positive definite matrices is compact) and so there must be a convergent subsequence by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee  Yes, we can show that the entire sequence converges to a degenerate operator (degenerate fixed points are plentiful). What's next?

Comment: How can the entire sequence of operators converge to a degenerate operator given the dynamic and initial conditions, which imply that $\det(X_k) = \det(X_0) \det(A)^k$?  My impression is that $\det(A)=1$ (in order to avoid degenerate situations), and thus, degenerate fixed points are inaccessible by this dynamic even asymptotically.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee As I said from the very beginning, $\det A<1$ is the only interesting case. Note that any power of a positive number is still positive, so no degenerate situations occur in that case.

Comment: The small font size makes it a bit difficult to read these comments. I see this point made in your earlier comment.  With a slight abuse of terminology, I regard the case $\det(A)>1$  as also degenerate, in the sense that the dynamics is asymptotically unstable in this regime.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Yeah, but that case is **trivial** because the trace is not less than the $n$-th root of the determinant (AM-GM), so it just blows up geometrically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you have completely solved it yourself, just didn't dare to acknowledge it. In my notation, you have $(X\circ X^T)v(A)=(Y\circ Y^T)v(I)$ when $Y^2=XAX$. Similarly, $(Z\circ Z^T)v(I)=(Y\circ Y^T)v(A)$ when $Z^2=YAY$. Taking the trace, we must have 
$$
1=\langle(X\circ X^T)v(I),v(I)\rangle=\langle(Y\circ Y^T)v(I),v(I)\rangle=\langle(Z\circ Z^T)v(I),v(I)\rangle\,.
$$
However,
$$
\langle(Y\circ Y^T)v(I),v(I)\rangle=\langle(X\circ X^T)v(A),v(I)\rangle
$$
and
$$
\langle(Z\circ Z^T)v(I),v(I)\rangle=\langle(Y\circ Y^T)v(A),v(I)\rangle
\\
=
\langle(Y\circ Y^T)v(I),v(A)\rangle=\langle(X\circ X^T)v(A),v(A)\rangle
$$
so 
$$
\langle(X\circ X^T)(v(A)-v(I)),(v(A)-v(I))\rangle=0
$$
whence $X\circ X^T$ and, thereby, $X$ must be degenerate unless $v(A)=v(I)$, i.e., $A=I$.

This story definitely has a few morals but I'll abstain from spelling them out :-).

Answer (score 2):

I sketch here a solution for the $2\times 2$ case. My hope is that the outlined approach can be used to find a general solution.

As noticed in *Addendum 1*, we can restrict wlog to diagonal positive definite $A$'s
$$
A := \begin{bmatrix}d_1 & 0 \\ 0 & d_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I consider the case $d_1>1$ and $0<d_2<1$, the other cases being trivial. Define $X_0^{1/2}$ as
$$
X_0^{1/2} := \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ b & c\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $X_0>0$ and hence $X_0^{1/2}>0$ it holds $a>0$, $b>0$, and $ac-b^2>0$. Moreover since $\mathrm{tr}(X_0)=1$, we have that
$$
a^2+2b^2+c^2=1. \quad (1)
$$
Now after one iteration step we obtain
\begin{align}
X_1 &= X_0^{1/2}AX_0^{1/2}= \begin{bmatrix} a^2d_1+b^2d_2 & \ast \\ \ast & b^2d_1+c^2d_2\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Due to the fact that $\mathrm{tr}(X_1)=1$, it follows that
$$
a^2d_1+b^2(d_1+d_2)+c^2d_2=1. \quad (2)
$$
Let us define
$$
X_1^{1/2} := \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ b_1 & c_1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $X_1=X_1^{1/2}X_1^{1/2}$, we get
\begin{align}
a_1^2+b_1^2=a^2d_1+b^2d_2 \ \ \text{ and }\ \ b_1^2+c_1^2=b^2d_1+c^2d_2.  \quad(\#)
\end{align}
Now consider the second iteration step
$$
X_2 = X_1^{1/2}AX_1^{1/2}= \begin{bmatrix} a_1^2d_1+b_1^2d_2 & \ast \\ \ast & b_1^2d_1+c_1^2d_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}(X_2) &= d_1(a_1^2+b_1^2)+d_2(b_1^2+c_1^2)\\
&\overset{(\#)}{=}a^2d_1+2b^2d_1d_2+c^2d_2^2=1,\quad (3)
\end{align}
by virtue of $(\#)$ and of the trace constraint $\mathrm{tr}(X_2)=1$. By collecting $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ we arrive at the following linear system
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\  d_1 & d_1+d_2 & d_2 \\ d_1^2 & d_1d_2 & d_2^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a^2 \\ b^2\\ c^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The solution $(\hat{a}^2, \hat{b}^2, \hat{c}^2)$ of the previous system — you can evaluate it manually or using some symbolic toolbox, as I did — is such that
$$
\sqrt{\hat a^2 \hat c^2}-\hat b^2 = \frac{|(d_1-1)(d_2-1)|+(d_1-1)(d_2-1)}{(d_1-d_2)^2}=0
$$
since $d_1>1$ and $0<d_2<1$, by assumption. But, in this case, we get that $X_0^{1/2}$ is singular, which is a contradiction since $X_0>0$.

---

**Update.** It is possible to generalize the above procedure to the case
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}d_1I_{n_1} & 0\\ 0&d_2I_{n_2}\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $d_1>1$ and $0<d_2<1$ scalars. Indeed, by considering the following block decomposition of $X_0^{1/2}$
$$
X_0^{1/2} := \begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ B^\top & C\end{bmatrix},
$$
by replacing $a$, $c$, and $b$ with $\mathrm{tr}(A^2)$, $\mathrm{tr}(C^2)$, and $\mathrm{tr}(B^\top B)$, and by following almost verbatim the above solution we get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me modify the given problem for the sake of simplicity.

---

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $X_0>0$ with unit trace, i.e.,
$$
X_0 = \sum_{1 \le i \le n} \lambda_i v_i v_i^T \;, \quad \sum_{1 \le i \le n} \lambda_i = 1 
$$ where $\{ \lambda_i \}$ and $\{ v_i \}$ are the positive eigenvalues and orthonormal eigenvectors of $X_0$, respectively.  Set $A>0$ to be 
$$
A = \sum_{1 \le i \le n} \alpha_i v_i v_i^T   \tag{$\diamond$}
$$
where $\{ \alpha_i \}$ are positive eigenvalues of $A$, and we stress that $A$ has the same eigenvectors as $X_0$. If the solution to the matrix recurrence relation 
$$
X_{k+1} = X_k^{1/2} A X_k^{1/2}
$$ with initial data $X_0$ satisfies $\operatorname{trace}(X_{k})=1$ for all natural numbers $k \ge 0$, then $A=I_n$, i.e., $\alpha_i = 1$ for all $1 \le i \le n$.

---

*Remark.* The difference between this formulation and the OP's formulation is that $A$ has the same eigenvectors as the given seed $X_0$. Admittedly, this form of $A$ is restrictive, but it is nicer to work with because, as we will see, it simplifies the subsequent calculations.

For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $A \ne I_n$, i.e.,  not all $\alpha_i = 1$ for $1 \le i \le n$. Since
$$
X_0^{1/2} = \sum_{1 \le i \le n} \sqrt{\lambda_i} v_i v_i^T 
$$
after one step of the recurrence relation we have that: 
\begin{align*}
X_1 &= \sum_{1 \le i,j \le n} \sqrt{\lambda_i} \sqrt{\lambda_j} (v_i^T A v_j) v_i v_j^T \\
&= \sum_{1 \le i,j,k \le n}\sqrt{\lambda_i} \sqrt{\lambda_j} \alpha_k (v_i^T v_k) (v_k^T v_j) v_i v_j^T \\
&= \sum_{1 \le i,j \le n}\sqrt{\lambda_i} \sqrt{\lambda_j} \alpha_i \delta_{ij} v_i v_j^T \qquad \text{($\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta)}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \alpha_i v_i v_i^T
\end{align*} and the unit trace requirement implies that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \alpha_i = 1 \;.
$$ Iterating the above calculation $k$ times, we see that the unit trace requirement  implies that $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \alpha_i^k = 1 $ which, according to our hypotheses, must hold true for any natural number $k \ge 0$. A more transparent way to write this requirement is as:
$$
\mathbf{V}^T \boldsymbol{\lambda} = \mathbf{1} \tag{$\star$}
$$
where we have introduced an infinite Vandermonde-like matrix and two vectors:
$$
\mathbf{V} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \alpha_1 & \cdots & \alpha_1^k & \cdots \\
1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_2^k & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \cdots \\
1 & \alpha_n & \cdots & \alpha_n^k & \cdots
\end{bmatrix} \;, \quad \boldsymbol{\lambda} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\
\vdots \\
\lambda_n \end{bmatrix} \;, \quad \mathbf{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\
1 \\
\vdots \end{bmatrix}
$$ If $\alpha_1 = \cdots =  \alpha_n = 1$, then the solution set of ($\star$) basically contains all unit trace matrices that are positive definite. (This is the trivial case.)   However, if even one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is not equal to one (the case at hand), then the solution set to this infinite (overdetermined) system of equations is empty, and there exists no $X_0$ that satisfies the hypotheses given above, which is a contradiction that is resolved only if $\alpha_1 = \cdots =  \alpha_n = 1$ or $A=I_n$.

Comment: Thanks! The approach is interesting, although restricted to a particular case.

Comment: Does the restriction that $A$ has the same eigenvectors as $X_0$ reduce the practicality of this result?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes

Comment: Could you please elaborate?  What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: It's a long story, but basically I would like to show that the iteration $(\star)$ has no invariant trajectories in the set of positive definite trace one matrices if $A\neq I$